# write data.frame to excel using R 3.1.2

Tags: r, export-to-excel

I'm looking for an easy way to write data directly to an excel file. Current packages such as xlsx and WriteXLS don't appear to work with the current version of R 3.1.2 (which I use through R studio).  Ideally I am looking for a package or function that can write a data.frame to excel in just a line or two of code.  Thank you.

Comment: Why not `write.csv()`?  You can easily open it in Excel.

Comment: That's what I do now, but I would love to be able to save the step. You can't just double click a .csv to open excel, you have to go through the import menus - unless you know a better way? Additionally, I export batches of files, so ideally would like to even be able to save various dataframes to multiple tabs within one excel file.

Comment: Hmm.  I've never had the issue of not being able to double click a .csv and have it open in Excel.  Maybe you need to associate .csv file-types with Excel?  Regardless, it sounds like @RussanKax provided a useful solution.

Comment: Have you tried the `XLConnect` package? Install and load that package, then type `?"workbook-class"`. The examples show you exactly how to do what you are asking.

Comment: The statement `don't appear to work with the current version of R 3.1.2` couldn't clearly identify the problem you have. I have no problem with `xlsx` package with `R 3.0.2`. If you provide code snippet and sample data, folks here could help provide better answers.

Comment: @KFB installing both xlsx and XLConnect warns that the package was built under an earlier version of R.  Loading the packages throws error messages about the 'rjava' package.  Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry

Comment: @MichaelBellhouse, Hmm... may be it's more a `rJava` issue. I saw similar issues popped up on SO sometime ago. My comment above is based on `Windows 7`.

Comment: @KFB yeah, it is starting to feel like that may be the confounding problem here. I reinstalled the rjava package but still getting the same error message.

Comment: @MichaelBellhouse, You could search `rJava` on SO for a possible solution or provide the code you used as suggested. Otherwise it'll be difficult for folks to provide an answer.

Comment: FWIW, `write.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package and the `XLConnect` code from @agstudy's answer seem to be working fine on my Mac with `R` 3.1.2 and `RStudio`.

Comment: @MichaelBellhouse an alternative for xlsx and XLConnect is openxlsx: `install.packages("openxlsx"); library(openxlsx); write.xlsx(x, file)` (you do not need Java for this) http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XLConnect` package. Here an example from the help:

```
# Load workbook (create if not existing)
wb <- loadWorkbook("writeWorksheet.xlsx", create = TRUE)
# Create a worksheet called 'CO2'
createSheet(wb, name = "CO2")
# Write built-in data set 'CO2' to the worksheet created above;
# offset from the top left corner and with default header = TRUE
writeWorksheet(wb, CO2, sheet = "CO2", startRow = 4, startCol = 2)
# Save workbook (this actually writes the file to disk)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: It's `XLConnect`, not `xlConnect`.

Comment: @agstudy, are you using R 3.1.2 and able to run your example with success?  I get error messages related to rjava dependent package

Comment: I get an error in the related package XLConnectJars: Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'XLConnectJars', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Answer (score 0):

The easier/more popular/less error-prone/portable, etc, way is probably to use `write.csv()`, the result of which will open fine in Excel.

Although, if you have Python installed, it is possible to write to `.xls` using the library `dataframes2xls`:

`df1<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9),3,3)); dataframes2xls::write.xls(df1,"data_table2.xls")`

Or in full:

```
install.packages("dataframes2xls")
library(dataframes2xls);
df1<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9),3,3));
write.xls(df1,"data_table2.xls")
```

Comment: running this example produces:[1] "Does 'python' exist, and is it in the path?"
Warning message:
running command 'python -c pass' had status 127

Comment: @MichaelBellhouse Oh yeah, you need Python installed...forgot about that. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataframes2xls/index.html I'll add that to my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks Rusan.  I just installed Python but really have no experience with it, not knowledgeable of how it works with R and R packages.  If I will hold onto your suggestion as a potential avenue to solving my problem in the future if I become more acquainted with Python.

Comment: @MichaelBellhouse Sure. I do use python, but as far as I can tell, you simply have to have it installed and available on the Windows PATH variable. Then the above package will work (I use this package myself) silently (i.e. you do not need to call Python, or do anything other than run the code R above). I certainly did not run/call Python when I ran my code example above. After installing Python - reinstall the dataframes2xls library, though. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this nowadays is probably the `openxlsx` package. It's easy to install, with no Java dependencies, and has a `write.xlsx` function which works much like `write.csv`. It only works with R > 3.3.0, though.